# Return today's missingrows from JOIN

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables, import_links and import_links_history

i have a php file fetching rows from the import_links, running a cron job and when it is done it inserts a row in import_links_history with the import_links.id and the timestamp so i now it is done. The cron jobs are running daily.

> How can i select rows where they have no entry today??

**structures summary**

```
import_links

- id
- other meaningless details

import_links_history

- id
- import_links_id
- created_at
```

**ddl**

```
CREATE TABLE import_links
(
  `id` int, 
  `productName` varchar(7)
)
;

CREATE TABLE import_links_history
(
  `id` int, 
  `import_links_id` int, 
  `created_at` timestamp
)
;
```

**current query**

```
SELECT import_links.id,import_links_history.created_at 
FROM import_links 
JOIN import_links_history 
ON import_links.id=import_links_history.id 
WHERE DATE(import_links_history.created_at) <> DATE(NOW()) 
ORDER BY import_links_history.created_at DESC
```

The above query is my try but it returns all the rows where date is now today. I need to returb from all today's rows the ones that are NOT present.

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3469a/1)

Can anyone help ?

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: @Strawberry here it is: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3469a/1
Need to return the rows of import_links where are not present in import_links_history today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**plan**

> - get ids in links history which match current date
> - select records from links whose id is not in above

---

**sample input**

```
+----+-----------------+--------------------------+
| id | import_links_id |        created_at        |
+----+-----------------+--------------------------+
|  1 |               1 | August, 03 2015 14:49:10 |
|  1 |               1 | August, 02 2015 14:49:10 |
|  2 |               3 | August, 03 2015 14:49:10 |
|  3 |               2 | July, 02 2015 14:49:10   |
+----+-----------------+--------------------------+
```

**query**

```
SELECT * 
FROM import_links
where id not in
(
  select distinct id
  from import_links_history
  where DATE(import_links_history.created_at) = current_date
  and id is not null
)
;
```

**output**

```
+----+-------------+
| id | productName |
+----+-------------+
|  3 | OpenDJ      |
+----+-------------+
```

valid as run with current_date of `August, 03 2015 00:00:00`

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ee7a13/4)

Comment: Some things are very easy to do but we think complicated.. thank you :)